Cannot call 'ta.stc' with argument 'fast'='high'. An argument of 'series float' type was used but a 'simple int' is expected
Trying to configure multi timeframe Stochastic indicator but getting above error.
Code:
TF_1_STC_K = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, time_frame1, ta.sma(ta.stc(close, high, low, 14), 3))
Any help is appreciated.
TF_1_STC_K = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, time_frame1, ta.sma(ta.stc(close, high, low, 14), 3))

I tired changing the ta.stc to ta.stoch in version 5 and gave a output ..here is code below..is this what you were looking for?
   // This Pine Script™ code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public 
  License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
  // © Codex Maximums
  //@version=5
  indicator("stoch", overlay = false)
  import TradingView/ta/7
  TF_1_STC_K = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, 
  timeframe.period,ta.sma(ta.stoch(close,high,low,14),3))
  plot(TF_1_STC_K)

